# Express as a product of reflections in lines the traslation in the vector whose origin is $(3,2)$ and end $(8,4)$

Tags: linear-transformations, reflection

im reading about Geometric Transformations, and i have a 
doubt...

Express as a product of reflections in lines the traslation in the vector 
whose origin is $(3,2)$ and end $(8,4)$

Can i used the formule,, im confused cause 
the formula is applied for a vector whose origin matches the origin of coordinates..

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the cooridinates of your vector. 
In general the coorcinates of vector with origin in $P=(p_1, p_2, ...,p_n)$ and end in $R=(r_1,r_2,..., r_n)$ are
$$\vec{V}=[r_1-p_1, r_2-p_2, ..., r_n-p_n]$$
Notice, that for the vector with origin in the coordinates origin is
$$\vec{V}=[r_1, r_2, ..., r_n]$$